# MySQL Sort Parent /Child based by sort field value

Tags: mysql

I've made a table to parent-child relationship (Sections/Subsections or Categories.Subcategories). I want to sort it first by parent 'SectionSort' field then by children '**SectionSort**' field.

Example table:

```
IDSection | SectionParentID | SectionSort | SectionName
-------------------------------------------------------
 2        |        0        |      2      | Chapter 2         
 1        |        0        |      1      | Chapter 1
 5        |        1        |      1      | Subchapter 1
 4        |        1        |      3      | Subchapter 3
 3        |        1        |      2      | Subchapter 2
 7        |        2        |      2      | Sunchapter 5
 6        |        2        |      1      | Subchapter 4
```

'SectionSort' filed can be dynamicaly change by moving up and down to column according user needs.

I need to get following result:

```
IDSection | SectionParentID | SectionSort | SectionName
-------------------------------------------------------
 1        |        0        |      1      | Chapter 1         
 2        |        0        |      2      | Chapter 2
 3        |        1        |      1      | Subchapter 1 
 4        |        1        |      2      | Subchapter 2
 5        |        1        |      3      | Subchapter 3
 6        |        2        |      1      | Sunchapter 4
 7        |        2        |      2      | Subchapter 5
```

Or something like this:

```
Chapter 1
 -Subchapter 1
 -Subchapter 2
   -..... 
 -SubChapter 3
Chapter 2
 -Subchapter 4
 -Subchapter 5
```

This is what I try but work only to next level not leve 3 ~ n:

```
SELECT EvalQuestions.*, Child.SectionSort AS Child_SectionSort, Parent.SectionParentsIDs AS Parent_SectionParentsIDs, Parent.SectionParentNames AS Parent_SectionParentNames,
Parent.SectionName AS Parent_SectionName, Parent.SectionSort AS Parent_SectionSort, Parent.SectionParentID AS Parent_SectionParentID 
FROM EvalQuestions INNER JOIN (EvalSections Parent INNER JOIN EvalSections Child ON
Parent.SectionParentID = Child.IDSection) ON
EvalQuestions.SectionID = Parent.IDSection 
ORDER BY Parent.SectionSort, Child.SectionSort, QuestionSort
```

Comment: With just a chapter and sub chapter it is easy enough. However if there are potentially infinite levels then not possible using your current design (mysql does not support recursive queries). Investigate the nested set model, which will allow many levels of parent / child relations. The alternative would be trying to build up the structure doing queries within a custom mysql function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select * from Table order by SectionParentID asc,SectionSort asc.
```

Comment: Thank you but each section and subsection has their dynamic (is often change by users) sort order and I dont want to order by SectionParentID .Each section can have unlimited subsection depth.I think is necessary something recursive in query but I dont know of how it can be done

Comment: I didn't get exactly what are you trying to say.Can you edit your question and give example of that.